# Is it correct to say that the constant of proportionality is proportional to the quantity itself?

Tags: mathematics

So for instance, according to Newtons Law of cooling the rate of cooling is proportional to the temperature difference between the object and its surroundings. Mathematically $$\frac{dT}{dt}=-k(T-T_s)$$

Can we say that $\frac{dT}{dt}$ is proportional to ${k}$ ?

Answer (score 3):

No.  $\frac{dT}{dt}$ is a variable whereas $k$ is a constant.  Proportionality means that two quantities vary in the same ratio.  If one varies but the other doesn't, they cannot be proportional.